# React mapped function running "setState" isn't updating component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an app component that takes one nested component. The nested component returns a number of buttons determined by one of its local state variable's lengths. Each button runs a programmatic this.setState() function to show a new set of data onClick. Here's the code described, and my question below:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='container'>
        <Buttons />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Buttons extends React.Component {
  state = {
    variableState,
    count: 0,
    chosen: 0,
  }
  upOne = x => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      count: prevState.count + 1,
      chosen: x,
    }))
    console.log('running')
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log('componentupdated')
  }
  render() {
    const {variableState, count, chosen} = this.state
    const {upOne} = this
    return (
      <div>
      {
        variableState[count].answers.map((s, t) => <button onClick={() => upOne(t + 1)}>{s}</button>)
      }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const variableState = [
  {
    answers: [
      'one',
      'two',
      'three',
      'four',
    ]
  }
]

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

I want to update the `<Buttons />` state by incrementing the count by one each time one of the buttons is clicked. This should run setState() which should update the component and run the componentDidUpdate() function. The problem is, the upOne() function runs, but it isn't updating the component and therefore not running the componentDidUpdate() function and I don't know why.

If I get rid of the Array.map() logic and make it a static function like this:

```
class Buttons extends React.Component {
    state = {
        variableState,
        count: 0,
        chosen: 0,
    }
    upOne = x => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            count: prevState.count + 1,
            chosen: x,
        }))
        console.log('running')
    }
    componentDidUpdate() {
        console.log('componentupdated')
    }
    render() {
        const {variableState, count, chosen} = this.state
        const {upOne} = this
        return (
            <button onClick={() => upOne(1)}>click</button>
        )
    }
}
```

It works as I expect it to.

Is this expected behavior or am I missing something?

Comment: I've dropped your code into a snippet, and when it runs, clicking a button clearly tries to re-render, but of course it fails because `count` is now `1` and `variableState` has only one entry in it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`variableState[count].answers`...

Once counts becomes `1`, `variableState[1]` is `undefined` and `undefined.answers` does not exists and you'll see an thrown error in your console.

I don't know if the `variableStates` value that you're showing in your code is the same as you're using on your end, but if you change it to `variableState[0].answers`..., it works.